# Getting the value of a Key from a JSON response which is made by parsing XML

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to parse an XML response from a URL and convert it to JSON the parsed response has so many unwanted data, however i only need the value of the attribute 'TEXT'

Tried getting the key by calling in  output = JSON.stringify(result); and returning return output['TEXT']; but it gives an undefined error.

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

function parse()
{

http.get('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=https://google.com', 
(resp) => {
let data = '';
// A chunk of data has been recieved.
resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
});
// The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
resp.on('end', () => {

//console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
    parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            output = JSON.stringify(result);

             });
});
}).on("error", (err) => {
console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});

return output['TEXT'];
}
```

This is the complete JSON which the parse function returns, i think its not valid. Im trying to get the 'TEXT' value inside 'POPULARITY'

```
{"ALEXA":{"$": 
   {"VER":"0.9","URL":"google.com/","HOME":"0","AID":"=","IDN":                                        
   "buymeacoffee.com/"},"SD":[{"POPULARITY":[{"$": 
   {"URL":"google.com/","TEXT"                                        
   :"20242","SOURCE":"panel"}}],"REACH":[{"$":{"RANK":"25887"}}],"RANK": 
   [{"$": 
   {"DEL                                        TA":"-21167"}}],"COUNTRY": 
   [{"$":{"CODE":"US","NAME":"United States","RANK":"2093                                        
   5"}}]}]}}
```

Comment: If you want to access properties of the object, you **don't** want to turn it into a string via `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Also, you cannot return `output` at the end of `parse()` due to the asynchronous nature of HTTP requests. Given your current code, I'd suggest passing a callback to `parse()` which you can call with the data you parse out, eg `callback(result.ALEXA.SD[0].POPULARITY[0].$.TEXT)`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding what you did wrong here:

- you don't need to stringify the result of `parseString`. It's an object already and you can use it as is.
- If you want to access `text`, you can do it by `result['ALEXA']['SD']['POPULARITY']['$']['TEXT']`

alternatively:

You can try using [camaro](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro). It is made specifically for this purpose: transforming xml to json and only take the properties you're interested in.

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

const xml = `

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Need more Alexa data?  Find our APIs here: https://aws.amazon.com/alexa/ -->
<ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="google.com/" HOME="0" AID="=" IDN="google.com/">
<SD><POPULARITY URL="google.com/" TEXT="1" SOURCE="panel"/><REACH RANK="1"/><RANK DELTA="+0"/><COUNTRY CODE="US" NAME="United States" RANK="1"/></SD></ALEXA>
`

;(async function () {
    const template = {
        text: 'ALEXA/SD/POPULARITY/@TEXT'
    }

    const result = await transform(xml, template)

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));

})()
```

Output:

```
{
    "text": "1"
}
```

the `text` property you want is accessible by using `result.text`